# Preferred approach to environmental building with Rake? (Coming from Msbuild/Nant)

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, rake, build-automation, nant

I have written and maintained a lot of Nant/Msbuild files, and have got a few problems in a current project where it seems that rake would make my life a lot easier. However I am a bit stumped on the first hurdle, but this may be because I am looking at the problem through Nant eyes.

To give some context here is how I normally expect my builds to be laid out (forgetting the actual physical structure, just look at what the components of it are):

```
- Root
  | - build-scripts
      | - default.build
      | - *.build
  | - build-properties
      | - dev.properties
      | - live.properties
      | - *.properties
  | - tools
      | - Nant
          | - Nant.exe
          | - *.*
      | - Nunit
          | - Nunit.exe
          | - *.*
      | - **/*.*
```

Now as you can see above the main components of a build are the build scripts, which contain the actual build instructions, the build properties, which are files containing purely the properties per environment. i.e

dev.properties may contain `web.service.url = "http://some.dev.address"` 
live.properties may contain `web.service.url = "http://some.live.address"`

Then there are the tools which are external executables used by the build scripts, such as Nant, Nunit, JsTestDriver etc.

Now focusing on my default.build file, this tends to contain a lot of upfront properties, such as directories used (i.e libs, output, package, project, tests) so they can all be evaluated up front. Then the other *.build files contain relevant build scripts, such as tests.build would deal with Nunit and run Unit/Integration/Acceptance tests etc.

The main problem for me here is that I have these environmental properties which configure the build for each environment, and then a lot of pre-defined properties which are overridden when invoked from the command line, i.e you would pass environment=live if you were building for a live environment, or if you left it blank it would default the environment to dev, and on the CI server it would set the environment to ci.

None of the examples I can find seem to tell me how to have default properties/variables that are overridden by the command line with Rake, I know you can set properties and get them out via the Env[] mechanism, but to use this I would need to set a global variable as normal then have a step which checks any env vars passed in and overwrite the global variables with those properties, also the only way I can see to allow external configuration files is to use global variables within them and include it, which I don't mind doing but I was hoping there was some best practises in this area I could learn from.

Also the final thing I was thinking about was that really the only variable to be passed in would be the environment (dev,ci,live etc) so I could make it so the default build task required an argument to be passed in, which is supported, but not sure if this is best as I would want it to run as "dev" if nothing was set, and this means you would always need to set one (not end of the world).

As you can see there are quite a few questions in this area, taking my existing approach and trying to adapt it to work with Rake. Any advice or information would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the proper answer, but I have basically kept the same soft of structure as above and used global variables for everything. So I have a properties file which contains something like:

```
$dir["project"] = "c:/Some/Project/Dir"
$dir["tests"] = "c:/Some/Tests/Dir"
$settings["auto-migrate-deltas"] = true
```

It is not really ideal, but it allows me to inject different properties based on the environment, it also makes alot of the build files less re-usable as they all use these global variables. Using parameter based tasks may make it more re-usable but there isn't a huge deal of documentation in this area and working examples, so I am just going to stick with the following system until I find a major problem.